# Unable to connect to mysql server database

Tags: mysql

**Problem**

**I am unable to connect to MYSQL server database**

This is what I have done.

I installed MYSQL Server 5.7.16 and was issued a temporary password.[image]

I went to

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

[image]

I entered sudo ./mysql -u root -p and was prompted to enter a password, I entered the temporary password given during MYSQL Installation(st*rukZV*5k<) and I received an error

```
"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) "
```

[image]

I even try it with no password by just hitting enter when I was prompted to enter a password  and I received an error

```
"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).
```

[image]

I even tried starting mysqld by running the following command and it says service already loaded.

```
sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

[image]

Please Help.

Comment: Have you tried to connect without sudo?

Comment: tried without sudo. can't connect as well.

Comment: Try `./mysql -u root --password=st*rukZV*5k<`  If still can't connect, try the same string with password in single or double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by the following steps.

1. stop mysqld by entering this command

   ```
   sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist]
   ```

   [image]

2.uninstalling the mysql server

```
sudo rm -rf mysql*
```

[image]

3.reinstall mysql server(new temporary password issued after reinstalling)

[image]

4. enter the command

   ```
   sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
   ```
5. go to /usr/local/mysql/bin

[image]

6. enter the command ./mysql -u root -h localhost -p followed by the new temporary password

[image]